# convert a $lookup result to an object instead of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a $lookup from a _id. So the result is always 1 document. Hence, I want the result to be an object instead an array with one item.

```
let query = mongoose.model('Discipline').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        project: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectId)
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "typecategories",
        localField: "typeCategory",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "typeCategory"
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1, typeCategory: "$typeCategory[0]"
      }
    }
  ]);
```

This notation: `"$typeCategory[0]"` is not working. Is there any smart way of doing this?

Comment: Use `typeCategory:{$arrayElemAt: ["$typeCategory", 0 ]}` for now. There is ticket out there to address this issue specifically https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27589

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22384
The link mentioned by @s7vr is closed as duplicate. This is the OPEN ticket.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can just use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). It deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element

```
let query = mongoose.model('Discipline').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        project: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectId)
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "typecategories",
        localField: "typeCategory",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "typeCategory"
      }
    },
    {$unwind: '$typeCategory'},
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1, typeCategory: "$typeCategory"
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Just putting it out here that $typeCategory used in $unwind is the name that is being returned here(as: "typeCategory") and, not that of localField.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in `$project` stage.

Syntax of `$arrayElemAt` is `{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idxexOfArray> ] }`

like:

```
mongoose.model('Discipline').aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
        project: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.projectId)
      },
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
        from: "typecategories",
        localField: "typeCategory",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "typeCategory"
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         name: 1, typeCategory: {$arrayElemAt:["$typeCategory",0]}
      }
   }
]);
```

Comment: Please note this syntax only works if you're not excluding properties in the projection. In your example, if name would be set to 0, you'd get a BadProjection error

Answer (score 3):

Use `$first` to return the first element in the array:

```
$project: {
    title: 1, 
    typeCategory: {$first: "$typeCategory"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For merging two collections:

```
{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$typeCategory", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }    }, 

{ $project: { typeCategory: 0 } }
```